# Interactive line graph in Python

Tags: python, svg, plot, interactive, bokeh

Is it possible to implement the following style of graph in Python?

http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/every-nba-teams-chance-of-winning-in-every-minute-across-every-game/

I specifically require being able to hover (or click) on a data point and the whole line is then highlighted while the others are made dull.

Comment: yes it is possible...... Check eg. matplotlib.org

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think matplotlib has mouse hover kind of feature

Comment: Yes, with Bokeh. This question should never have been closed (@vaultah, Jack Maney, l4mpi, Burhan Khalid, Odedra). The question was clearly asking how to get the interactivity. The question is well-defined, on-topic and not "too broad". +1

Comment: Dan: do you want this in the browser, or in a standalone Python session?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) is probably your best bet, although there are also a lot of newer libraries such as [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) with similar functionalities.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576454/python-and-matplotlib-and-annotations-with-mouse-hover) for more detail on how to use Matplotlib and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453143/point-and-line-tooltips-in-matplotlib/4620352#4620352), for a better hover implementation.

Here's a great walk-through of a variety of options for making this sort of graph: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/msund/11349097

Comment: Disagree. For interactive and on the web Bokeh is almost certainly a better choice.

Comment: Yes, now that Bokeh has had two years to mature, that is probably true.