# Matplotlib invisible annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently just adding some points into a graph and adding annotation for each specific point. However, on every try, only a subset of the annotations actually show up on my screen. The other annotations are "there" via debugging and prints, but they are just not visible for some reason. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

self.fig = plt.figure()
self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

li = [[0.2, 1], [0.4, 1], [0.6, 1], [0.8, 1], [1, 1]]

for x,y in li:
  point, = self.ax.plot(x, y, marker='o', color='r', markersize=12)
  annotation = self.ax.annotate("Comment goes here",
      xy=(x,y), xycoords='data',
      xytext=(x,y), textcoords='data'
  )

self.fig.canvas.draw()
```

After some debugging, it seems that removing the `projection='polar'` fixes the issue and all of the annotations show up. Is there something specific with polar graphs that will cause buggy annotations?

Edit: Actually, I might have oversimplified the problem.. I tried the simplified version of the program and it worked. I am working off an existing framework built on top of matplotlib and gtk+, so there might be some other hidden issue that I am unaware of.

Edit2: I have traced the problem. It seems that, in my update function, if I set ylim for the graph (radius) to be 1 (which is the same as all of the points), then some of the annotations disappear. No idea why, but it works if I leave the ylim alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

No repro for me on `matplotlib.__version__` 1.3.x, all your annotations show up in the specified positions.

Comment: Ah I am using version 1.0.1, I wonder if it's a bug in the older version.. thanks for your input!

Comment: Actually, interestingly I might have oversimplified the problem in the original post.. I tried the simplified version of the program and it still worked. I am working off an existing framework built on top of matplotlib, so there might be some other hidden issue that I am unaware of.