# Make a label / annotation appear, when hovering over an area (rectangle)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

As you can see the question above, I was wondering, if it is possible to popup a label, when I hover on a rectangle-area.

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537374/matplotlib-basemap-popup-box/11556140#11556140) which helped me for popping up a label over a **point**.

But is it possible to popup a label, when the user hovers somewhere over an area?

On my plot, I'm using this code example for adding rectangles:

http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/

Let's use this as example:

[image: Hover square]
<sub>(source: [matthiaseisen.com](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/static/p0203_1.png))</sub>

When the user hovers (everywhere) over the blue area, a popup "You are hovering over the blue area" should appear.

Is this even possible in matplotlib? I can't find any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib by itself isn't going to give you this functionality. Bokeh [(link)](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html), another python library, is what you want. [Here is an example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html) with the hovertool feature, which is what you're looking for. You can even export the image as html so you can put it on a website or blog.