# Matplotlib, Jupyter: Have annotation appearing when hovering over plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot with matplotlib that has tooltip appearing when hovering hover certain elements of the charts. I want to do that in the **Jupyter Notebook**, with python 3.

I have tried the snippets provided here:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html
[Possible to make labels appear when hovering over a point in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib)
[Is there a matplotlib equivalent of MATLAB's datacursormode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652439/is-there-a-matplotlib-equivalent-of-matlabs-datacursormode/4674445#4674445)
[Matplotlib basemap: Popup box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537374/matplotlib-basemap-popup-box/11556140#11556140)

But none of them work. The plot shows but is not interactive.
I tried with and without the magic `%matplotlib inline` with no effect.
I of course also modified the print statement when it was without parenthesis.
**Is there a specific command or backend to use in order to have the interaction working in Jupyter?**

EDIT:
the example working with mpld3 "works" but i would rather stick to the basic matplotlib.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want `%matplotlib notebook`. This will integrate interactive plots in the notebook.

Comment: Yep that was the solution. However do you know how to remove the pan/zoom tool at the bottom left of the plot and the "figure" header at the top of the `%matplotlib notebook` display? They are distracting and inesthetic

Comment: I don't know. I remember (vaguely) trying to remove the toolbar with this backend and failing. This is something that deserves its own question in SO if there isn't one yet.